# Does BigQuery JSON export keep uppper/lower case for column names？

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery's column names are case-insensitive.
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical)

As far as I tried (below), it seems BigQuery to keep uppper/lower cases for column names when export.

```
$ bq show --format=sparse sandbox.case_test

   Last modified         Schema        Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Time Partitioning   Labels 
 ----------------- ------------------ ------------ ------------- ------------ ------------------- --------
  11 Sep 12:46:02   |- small: string   1            12                                                    
                    |- LARGE: string
```

This tables has both upper and lower case names.

```
$ bq extract --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON  sandbox.case_test gs://sandbox/case_test.json


$ gsutil cat  gs://sandbox/case_test.json
{"small":"hoge","LARGE":"buzz"}
```

Does anyone know any documents which mention this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While column *references* are case sensitive, column names as *stored* in metadata preserve case. I don't think there is documentation that says, "BigQuery stores the original column names that you give it and uses them as the field names for exports," but I can confirm that it does.

Answer (score 2):

Column names are case-insensitive means that you can - not worry about case when you reference columns in you SELECT statements. For example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT small, LARGE 
FROM `project.sandbox.case_test`
```

and

```
 #standardSQL
SELECT sMAll, LarGE 
FROM `project.sandbox.case_test`
```

will respectively produce result w/o any failure

```
Row small   LARGE    
1   hoge    buzz     

Row sMAll   LarGE    
1   hoge    buzz
```

Note, column names being case-insensitive does not mean they will be changed during export - rather names set in schema will be used
*I doubt this is reflected specifically anywhere in documentation as it is something that I would consider obvious*